# Travis autoloader PhpUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci

This is my PHPUnit configuration file. for some reason it works on my local enviorment but when i'm trying using travis its saying that it can't find the classes for some reason.

and bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php" is not found on the Travis machine

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.2/phpunit.xsd"
             backupGlobals="false"
             verbose="true"
             bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">
        <testsuite name="aaaa">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <logging>
            <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage"/>
        </logging>

        <filter>
            <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
                <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
            </whitelist>
        </filter>
    </phpunit>
```

Comment: Just guessing, but are you using composer? You may need to have composer install dependencies on travis before the test will work.

Comment: yes, thats was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using composer, it installs the autoloader and any dependencies to the `vendor` directory. It is common to put the `vendor` directory into your `.gitignore` file.

This means that when travis checks out your project, it will not have the vendor directory. You need to run composer to **install the dependencies** and autoloader before running your tests.

Make sure to commit your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files and put this into your `.travis.yml`:

```
install: composer install
```